# How to use Sum on groupBy result in Spark DatFrames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Based on the following dataframe:

```
+---+-----+----+
| ID|Categ|Amnt|
+---+-----+----+
|  1|    A|  10|
|  1|    A|   5|
|  2|    A|  56|
|  2|    B|  13|
+---+-----+----+
```

I would like to obtain the sum of the column Amnt groupby ID and Categ.

```
+---+-----+-----+
| ID|Categ|Count|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|    A|  15 |
|  2|    A|  56 |
|  2|    B|  13 |
+---+-----+-----+
```

In SQL I would be doing something like

```
SELECT ID,
       Categ, 
       SUM (Count) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY ID,
         Categ;
```

But how to do this in Scala?
I tried

```
DF.groupBy($"ID", $"Categ").sum("Count")
```

But this just changed the Count column name into `sum(count)` instead of actually giving me the sum of the counts.

Comment: you have to use aggregation and use alias `df.groupBy("ID", "Categ").agg(sum("Amnt").as("Count"))`  and of course you need to `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum` :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan's solution worked for me but the one below did not.

Comment: @ Amr A., for complex aggregation (such as multiple aggregations) or renaming aggregated column, one would need to wrap the aggregation(s) with `agg`.  See my expanded answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you were summing the wrong column, but your `grougBy/sum` statement looks syntactically correct to me:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "A", 10),
  (1, "A", 5),
  (2, "A", 56),
  (2, "B", 13)
).toDF("ID", "Categ", "Amnt")

df.groupBy("ID", "Categ").sum("Amnt").show
// +---+-----+---------+                                                           
// | ID|Categ|sum(Amnt)|
// +---+-----+---------+
// |  1|    A|       15|
// |  2|    A|       56|
// |  2|    B|       13|
// +---+-----+---------+
```

EDIT:

To alias the `sum(Amnt)` column (or, for multiple aggregations), wrap the aggregation expression(s) with [`agg`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset@agg(expr:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame).  For example:

```
// Rename `sum(Amnt)` as `Sum`
df.groupBy("ID", "Categ").agg(sum("Amnt").as("Sum"))

// Aggregate `sum(Amnt)` and `count(Categ)`
df.groupBy("ID", "Categ").agg(sum("Amnt"), count("Categ"))
```

Comment: For beginners, don't forget to import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._